# Different RAM Speeds (Same Hardware)

Tags: memory, speed, ddr3

I've got 4 DIMMs of RAM (GSkill Ripjaws), they are supposed to run at 1600Mhz. When I check the speeds, my BIOS tells me that slot 1&3 are running at 1600 and 2&4 at 1333. I tried to set it manually and via XMP. Now I wonder, why aren't they running at the same speed?
What can I do to make them do it?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, when one of the RAM modules is running slower, the other modules should follow, so they should all run at the same speed.
However, some computers set the speed of the RAM modules accordingly to what is needed automatically.
This can also occur when putthing more than 3GB of RAM in a 32-bit system.

Comment: Erm.  I don't think the speed of the memory changes because it goes over the OS' limits.

Comment: i am running win 7 64bit pro, so there should be no limitations. I got 4x4Gb GSkill Ripjaw Dimms. They seem to be running at different speeds, no downclocking or sth, just different freqs from start to finish

Comment: @envalid: ... 32-bit can mean hardware or software. And in this case I wasn't talking about the OS.
@rootman: Well, it's strange... Could you install a monitoring utility and tell me what it says? Maybe it tells you something different than the BIOS screen?